# How to find the element chosen from my two objects

Tags: javascript

I have two objects options and choosed,
for example

```
var options = ["ch1","ch2","ch3","ch4"];
var choosed = ["ch2","ch4"];
```

I want the result to be

```
var result = [];
result[0]={option:"ch1", res:false};
result[1]={option:"ch2", res:true};
result[2]={option:"ch3", res:false};
result[3]={option:"ch4", res:true};
```

ch2 and ch4 are chosen so the result will be true, how to make loops to obtain this result ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? What have you found in your research?

Comment: Use nested for-loops. The outer loop through `options`.

Comment: Any JavaScript tutorial should cover how to iterate (over arrays).

Comment: E.g. http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#h_FaGGgUI+MM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
var options = ["ch1","ch2","ch3","ch4"];
var choosed = ["ch2","ch4"];
var result = [];

options.forEach(function(e) {
  result.push({option: e, res: choosed.indexOf(e) !== -1});
})

console.log(result)
```

Or you can also do this with `reduce`

```js
var options = ["ch1","ch2","ch3","ch4"];
var choosed = ["ch2","ch4"];

var result = options.reduce(function(a, e) {
  a.push({option: e, res: choosed.indexOf(e) !== -1});
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `Array.forEach` isn't supported below IE9 and is slower than the standard `for` loop. Along with that the OP seems to be a beginner in JavaScript, I would not be surprised if they didn't know the ternary operator.

Comment: `result.push({option: e, res: choosed.indexOf(e) > -1})` seems to be cleaner than the conditional operator (but: opinion ;) )

Comment: @Felix Kling I agree but its Marcus's idea so i am going to leave it like this.

Comment: @NenadVracar - You got the *accepted* answer. I don't mind if you add to it using parts from my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through your `options[]` array using `forEach()` and a *callback* function, and `push()` the results into a `result[]` array.

`choosed.indexOf(e) !== -1` will return `bool(true|false)` depending on whether a match (by way of an index/key check, using indexOf()) from `choosed[]` was found in `options[]`

```js
var options = ["ch1","ch2","ch3","ch4"],
    choosed = ["ch2","ch4"],
    result = [];

options.forEach(function (e) {
    result.push({
        option: e,
        res: choosed.indexOf(e) !== -1
    })
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will go over the more basic and understandable way of solving this, rather than relying on JavaScript functions to do the work for you. This also will have support in older browsers. Using two standard nested for-loops, and the solution you would use in pseudo-code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var found = false;
    for(var j = 0; j < choosed.length; j++) 
        if( options[i] == choosed[j] ) 
            found = true;
    result.push({'option': options[i], res: found});
}
```

We iterate over the `options` array to check for each element. We first assume that it is not found, then we iterate over the `choosed` array. When a match is found we change `found` to `true`. Finally we add the results to the `result` array.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kd6xg54t/) of the above implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use two passes, one for `choosed` and one for generating the result array.

It uses an object for the `res` property, because indexOf perform not very well (with larger data sets).

```js
var options = ["ch1", "ch2", "ch3", "ch4"],
    choosed = ["ch2", "ch4"],
    temp = Object.create(null),
    result;

choosed.forEach(function (a) {
    temp[a] = true;
});

result = options.map(function (a) {
    return { option: a, res: !!temp[a] };
});

console.log(result);
```